# Keyword Searching for User-owned Images

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, search

I know Google's powerful image search feature but it's searching images from the entire Internet.. Until recently, I discovered they apply image search to Google+ photos. That means you can search your own photos by keywords.

I'm wondering if there's any API/Lib (provided by Google) so that I can use directly... To be more specific, I'm working on Google App Engine. I know there are [Image API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) and [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/).. I have not found Image Search API yet. And I don't know if this [deprecated image search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/) does the job I want..

I'm really trying my luck to ask this question!